# Yii how to highlight the current label

Tags: yii, yii1.x

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
   'Dailymarket Reports',
);

$this->menu=array(
   array('label'=>'inbox', 'url'=>array('index')),
   array('label'=>'sent', 'url'=>array('sent')), 
);
```

Above I have two labels. I want `inbox` to be default active label if mouse moves out and selects `sent` as active it should be highlighted.

Comment: The code provided is unrelated to the question you are asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about how to show the menu item selected according to the current route if you are on `Home` page then the `Home` menu item should be selected.

Although you can see solutions like adding checks but if you provide full path to your link you won't have to add any further checks for activating the menu items, just make sure you are not passing `activateItems=>false` inside the `CMenu` widget in the layout file, otherwise it defaults to `true` and it decides whether to automatically activate items according to whether their route setting matches the currently requested route.

Go to your view where you are adding the `menu` specify a full path like `/controller/action` for your links for example if I have a menu for the site controller `SiteController` actions I will provide paths like below.

```
$this->menu=array(
   array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')), 
   array('label'=>'Demo', 'url'=>array('/site/demo')), 
);
```

and that's it you can make it work if you don't need to add separate checks for every menu item.

Just make sure you have a `css` class for `li.active > a` so that you can get the highlighted effect,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `active` class for specified items:

```
$this->menu = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'inbox', 'url' => array('index'), 
        'active' => $this->action->id === 'index' ? true : null,
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'sent', 'url' => array('sent'),
        'active' => $this->action->id === 'sent' ? true : null,
    ),
);
```

You need to style items with `active` class yourself.

---

You may also omit specifying `url` for current item, so it will be displayed as text instead of link:

```
$this->menu = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'inbox',
        'url' => $this->action->id === 'index' ? null : array('index'),
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'sent',
        'url' => $this->action->id === 'sent' ? null : array('sent'),
    ),
);
```